# Color detection of traffic light without using masking and pixels

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, yolov8

I am using masking and pixels method to detect the traffic light color but it is not giving accurate results

Tried with this code it is working but not giving accurate results

Expecting: it should detect a proper color in traffic light

how can i make this code in such a way so that it should work correctly without using ,masking and pixels and give accurate results

````py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from ultralytics import YOLO
import math
import time
import os

# Initialize YOLO model
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
video_path = './v3.mp4'

# Initialize video capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

fw = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
fh = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

def detect_color(frame, roi):
    # Convert ROI to HSV color space
    hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    # Define the color ranges
    red_lower = np.array([0, 120, 70]) 
    red_upper = np.array([10, 255, 255])     
    red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, red_lower, red_upper)
    
    yellow_lower = np.array([18, 100, 100]) 
    yellow_upper = np.array([30, 255, 255]) 
    yellow_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, yellow_lower, yellow_upper) 
    
    green_lower = np.array([40, 60, 60]) 
    green_upper = np.array([90, 255, 255]) 
    green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, green_lower, green_upper)
    
    # Count the number of non-zero pixels in each mask
    red_pixel_count = cv2.countNonZero(red_mask)
    yellow_pixel_count = cv2.countNonZero(yellow_mask)
    green_pixel_count = cv2.countNonZero(green_mask)
    
    # Determine the color with the highest pixel count
    max_count = max(red_pixel_count, yellow_pixel_count, green_pixel_count)
    
    # Return the color with the highest pixel count
    if max_count == red_pixel_count:
        return 'Red'
    elif max_count == yellow_pixel_count:
        return 'Yellow'
    else:
        return 'Green'

def main():
    fps_start_time = time.time()  # Start time for FPS calculation
    frame_count = 0 
    
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        results = model(frame, stream=True)

        for r in results:
            boxes = r.boxes
            for box in boxes:
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0]  # Extract coordinates
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
                conf = math.ceil((box.conf[0] * 100)) / 100
                cls = box.cls[0]  # Class ID
                
                if conf > 0.45 and cls == 9:                
                    # Region of interest
                    roi = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]
                    detected_color = detect_color(frame, roi)
                    
                    # Draw bounding box in white
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(x1), int(y1)), (int(x2), int(y2)), (255, 255, 255), 4)
                    
                    # Display the detected color in white text
                    cv2.putText(frame, f'{detected_color}', (x1, y1 - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
                        
        # Resize the frame
        resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1280, 720))    
        # Display the frame
        cv2.imshow("Traffic light detection", resized_frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()```


[in this picture there is no any color in the traffic light but still it is detecting it as red][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFA0y.jpg


My doubt is, how can i proceed with the code without using masking thing
````

Comment: What is wrong with that approach?  Just saying it is not accurate is insufficient to explain your issue. Please show input and results you get where it fails.  If it is red values, that may be because red in HSV needs two ranges (depending upon color) --- one at 0 and above and the other at 180 and below.